# Access string from another class

Tags: android

I have different packages in my app like this.

[image]

CansTypeObject class looks like this

```
public class CansTypeObject {
    String productId;
    String productName;
    String productPrice;
    String productReturnPrice;
    String productImage;
}
```

Now, I want to access these strings from MainActivity

```
CansTypeObject object = new CansTypeObject();
```

But I cant. If I move the CansTypeObject class to the same package as that of MainActivity, I can access them. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The default scope is package-private. Use the public modifier on the String declaration

```
public String productId;
```

Comment: default is package. Not private.

Comment: oh.. silly how I missed scope of individual Strings. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The **only reason** of this behavior is that you declared yours class Strings as *package-protected* strings. In Java this means, that this fields will be accessible only for classes in the same package.

There are several solutions for your problem. 
The first (and the worst) - declare your fields as **public** strings, like this:

```
public String myField;
```

The second - create getters for your fields and declare your strings as **private** fields, like this:

```
private String myField;

public String getMyField() {
    return myField;
}
```

Then, use this getters on your class object.

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `getter-setter` method for the `CansTypeObject` class as follows for accessing them easily:

```
public class CansTypeObject {
    String productId;
    String productName;
    String productPrice;
    String productReturnPrice;
    String productImage;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(String productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductReturnPrice() {
        return productReturnPrice;
    }

    public void setProductReturnPrice(String productReturnPrice) {
        this.productReturnPrice = productReturnPrice;
    }

    public String getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(String productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }
}
```

for creating getter-setter method you can use shortcut key for

`MAC - command + N`

`Windows - Alt + Insert`

Another way is to open the class for which you have to make getter setter and then `right click and from the context menu select Generate option`